# Are these usages of OWIN possible?

Tags: asp.net, hosting, web-hosting, self-hosting, owin

Is it possible to write a simple custom Console Application that includes a owin library that can host a Asp.Net Web Application directly (without katana.exe, like CassiniDev's library)?
Is it possible to let an Asp.Net Web Application including MVC 4, Web API, SignalR features hosted across IIS and owin, without / rarely changing code?

Comment: Sure. Check out this sample http://goo.gl/SyKOp

Comment: But I don't think Nancy equals to ASP.NET MVC. I think Nancy is another framework besides ASP.NET MVC, is it right?

Comment: OWIN will let you host Web API and SignalR in a console application. Not MVC or WebForms, but you could substitute Nancy for that

Comment: OK, if I want to migrate existing full-functioned ASP.NET MVC project to be hosted in a console application, what's the choice? Cassini?

Comment: for asp.net mvc, I don't think this is possible today.

Comment: Well, no solution is still an answer, @cecilphillip, thank you, will you please put answer below and I'll finish this thread..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For hosting applications from the ASP .NET framework family on top of OWIN, as of this post, you can do so with [WebAPI](http://goo.gl/bNzzj) and [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host). If you need something more like MVC and Razor, you can look at using the [NancyFX](http://goo.gl/PCAhK) web app framework for that. Maybe in future versions of MVC OWIN support will be enabled

Comment: With Webapi2.0 there is a small update to this http://www.strathweb.com/2013/10/asp-net-web-api-2-is-out-overview-of-features/ point 2.

Answer (score 0):

I did an initial implementation of adapter at https://github.com/ashmind/Gate.Adapters.AspNet.
It is absolutely not production ready, but if the functionality is important for you you are welcome to test/extend it.

As far as I know there is no other reliable library for that.